# Querying a database via search bar php

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I wanted to create a search bar, Final.php is a display page for every event the user has inputted into the database but I want to add a search bar to query the list to find the result they want faster (the event names and four scores for each team). I don't understand where I have gone wrong, I hope someone can help.

---

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id5052875_signuplogin", "Meganruby2") or die("cannot connect");
mysqli_select_db($con, "id5052875_signuplogin") or die ("couldnt connect");
$output = '';

    //collect
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);
    print("$searchq");
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM event WHERE event name LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("could not search");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    echo($searchq);
    if($count == 0 ) {
        $output = 'There was no search';

    }else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $event = $row['event name'];
            $num1 = $row['Score1'];
            $num2 = $row['Score2'];
            $num3 = $row['Score3'];
            $num4 = $row['Score4'];


            $output .= '<div> '.$event.' '.$num1.' '.$num2.' '.$num3.' '.$num4.'</div>';

            }

        }



    }
?>    
<form action="Final.php" method="post">
    <input type = "text" name = "search" placeholder = "search for event.."/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah sorry just trying to do it, only just got this website so having difficulty :)

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: nothing, no errors but no result either, even when using <?php print($output) ?>

Answer (score 0):

Your first condition, change

`if ( isset( $_POST['event'] ) ) {` to `if ( isset( $_POST['search']  ) ) {`

and

`$searchq = $_POST['search'];` to `$searchq = $_POST['search'];`

The name of the search text input is 'search', but for some reason, you are looking for event.

Also, please not that you are taking direct user input and inserting it into a DB query. Please be careful of SQL injection. This is a common [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/5749295) to check and learn more about preventing it.

Comment: ive done that but now my $query isn't working, Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /storage/ssd2/875/5052875/public_html/Final.php on line 23
could not search

Comment: `$output` was never displayed because the if condition was never true, you were looking for the wrong field. Now that you are in the if block, your query needs fixing. `mysqli_query` expects two arguments, the SQL connection, and the query. You are only supplying the query at the moment, please read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: okay thank youuuu!

Comment: The biggest thanks is with rep or answer! @RubyWatts

Comment: @RubyWatts for almost every question there is some solution available on SO, so before posting your question try to google it :)

Comment: I did google it but im inexperience and don't understand